# c# is и or для непостоянных переменных

Tags: c#, рефакторинг

Только что благодаря Resharper'у узнал о такой замечательной штуке как is и or, которые позволяют писать не так

```cs
if((SomeStringWithLongName=="true")||(SomeStringWithLongName=="yes")||(SomeStringWithLongName=="да")||(SomeStringWithLongName=="1")) Do();
```

а так!

```cs
if(SomeStringWithLongName is "true" or "yes" or "да" or "1") Do();
```

Но is и or можно использовать только для постоянных значений, а есть ли подобные штуки, которые позволяют сократить написание таких конструкций для **непостоянных** переменных? Например:

```cs
if((SomeVariableWithLongName==Var1)||(SomeVariableWithLongName==Var2)||(SomeVariableWithLongName==Var3)||(SomeVariableWithLongName==Var4)) Do();
```

где Var# – непостоянные строки или другие сравнимые типы

Comment: Решение сильно зависит от контекста. Чаще случается, если у вас такой длинный `if`, да ещё и с зависимостью от именованных переменных, значит что-то пошло не так, и код в целом можно улучшить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, к сожалению, pattern-matching работает лишь с константными значениями.

Но можно, например, написать так:

```
if (new[] { Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4 }.Contains(SomeStringWithLongName)) Do();
```

Это немножко менее эффективно, т. к. создаёт лишний массив и копирует в него значения, но обычно такой неэффективностью можно пренебречь.

---

Ещё одна разница — это то, что массив + Contains вычисляет значения выражений `Var1`, ... *энергично* (то есть, все и сразу), а `||` лениво (то есть, только те, что надо и тогда, когда понадобились) вследствие short-circuit-логики. Для случая простых переменных это, разумеется, не большая проблема, а вот для сложных выражений могут быть <s>нюансы</s> тонкости.